# Rails, S3, Paperclip changes attachment file .epp extension to .txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, attachment

I have trouble setting my application correctly, to store attachments with `.epp` extension (which has `file -b --mime-type = text/plain`) and serve them to users with correct extenstion (it changes to `.txt`).

After adding to initializers:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  :epp => 'text/plain'
}
```

I am able to upload the file to s3, without receiving the `spoofed_media_type` error. However, when I try to serve the file for user with:

```
redirect_to @job.file.expiring_url
```

it downloads with `.txt` extension. The file is saved with the following code in the job class:

```
...
has_attached_file :file, :s3_permissions => 'authenticated-read', :s3_headers => {"Content-Disposition" => "attachment"}
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file
...
self.file = File.open(file_path)
self.save!
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

**Update:**
Actually it happens only with Chrome, Firefox downloads the file correctly, so it might be the browser issue...

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your `paperclip.rb` initializer looks something like this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Try changing the path to include the extension like so:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename.:extension'
```

Comment: After adding `/:filename.:extension` as suggested, it's saving as `filename.epp.epp` to s3 and downloading as `filename.epp.txt` so it doesn't solve the issue, thank You anyways

Comment: I think the s3 is serving the file with extension based on the mime-type, and I don't know how to prevent it; because the file saves correctly as `filename.epp`

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I think you are right, in that it seems to be a mime-type issue. Have you tried just setting the content type to `application/octet-stream`? From the RFC http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt
"The 'octet-stream' subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data."